# Query on DATE type in Qgis ?

Tags: qgis, csv, query

I am presently working with some open data in an original .csv file format with some lat, long columns.

I want to do a "Select by expression for each mouth" :
if I do for example : "DATE" > 2016-01-01 it select all the rows in the table.

I believe it could be a problem of data format in the column, but I am not sure.

Does someone know how I could confirm my query is correct and it is a way to confirm the data type in the column "DATE" ?

[image]

Comment: How it looks if you enter '2016-01-01', not 2016-01-01 ?

Comment: Check the field type (Layer properties and Fields tab). It is probably not DATE. When you import csv you can use a csvt file to define field types (see: https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution "Kazuhito" if I use :
"DATE" < '2016-01-01' I get result.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, Sébastien :) For your further work you may find [User Guide](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html) helpful. I wish it had expounded on **'string'** a little more detail with examples...(just a thought).